# how to alignment angular material tab vertically?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I used angular material in my current project and I faced one problem when using angular material tab. I want to used this tab vertically but it's not working properly. It's like alignment are just break, It's not working normally as I want. Anyone can give me a proper solution how can I fixed this angular material tab vertically?

HTML code:

```
 <md-content class="md-padding" >
                    <md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="data.selectedIndex" layout="row">
                      <md-tab id="tab1" >
                        <md-tab-label>Item One</md-tab-label>
                        <md-tab-body>
                          View for Item #1 <br/>
                          data.selectedIndex = 0;
                        </md-tab-body>
                      </md-tab>
                      <md-tab id="tab3">
                        <md-tab-label>Item Three</md-tab-label>
                        <md-tab-body>
                          View for Item #3 <br/>
                          data.selectedIndex = 2;
                        </md-tab-body>
                      </md-tab>
                      <md-tab id="tab3">
                        <md-tab-label>Item Three</md-tab-label>
                        <md-tab-body>
                          View for Item #3 <br/>
                          data.selectedIndex = 2;
                        </md-tab-body>
                      </md-tab>
                    </md-tabs>
                </md-content>
```

Comment: make a plunker so that we can see your problem

Comment: There is no Material Design spec for vertical tabs. Why not use a side nav?

Comment: @roope i want to use tab functionally by using angular material. if there is no option then i have to use sidenav here. tnx for ur comment :)

Answer (score 0):

As per current version of Material tabs can be placed on top and bottom by setting the attribute value.There is no option to set it vertical.

However there is third party JS which can help you with this.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs